# Wire Size for 400AH (2 @ 200ah) battery bank with 4000w inverter?

Tags: wiring, parallel

I have 2 12v 200AH Renogy batteries I’d like to create a 12v 400ah battery bank from.

I am trying to figure out what gauge of wire to use for connecting these batteries together in parallel.

My inverter is 4000 watts, 3% voltage drop is what I’m after.

I have run a few calculators and received different answers, so thought I’d come here for a sanity check.

Comment: What were the answers from the calculators, to check their values? And what does the inverter manual say about wire size? Which inverter is it? How far apart are the batteries and how far from inverter, as wiring distance affects the wire diameter.

Comment: https://www.solar-wind.co.uk/info/dc-cable-wire-sizing-tool-low-voltage-drop-calculator

I input 3% loss, 12v system voltage, 333.333 amps (4000w / 12v) and .3 meters of wire and it came up with 3/0 AWG. It’s an energizer 4000w inverter, about 3 feet away (the inverter includes 3ft 0 wag cables)

Comment: In the worst case scenario, one of your batteries is disconnected under full load.  Your inverter is 4kW at an unknown efficiency, so the 333A figure is a minimum.  My chart shows that 3/0 is too small for that current so 4/0 would be appropriate.  This further depends on the temp rating of your wire, ambient temperature of the installation, maximum possible load on the inverter, etc.  If you are trying to use smaller wire to connect the batteries together, you'll need to fuse it to protect from the open circuit condition, which might negate any cost savings from the wire.

Comment: Does it change anything if the biggest load I plan to use is 2000w? (It’s an induction stove, may briefly surge higher when starting it)

Comment: Don't forge that you need to have two cables with two voltage drops so the total length of cable is 0.6 meters, not 0.3. Your distances seems confused. If the inverter is 3 feet from the battery that is almost 1 meter. So there are 2 meters total wire length.

Comment: @KevinWhite The distance I gave is from roughly from 1 battery to the other if I wired them in parallel. I believe that distance is shorter in reality. The length of the (0 awg) cables included with my inverter is 3 ft

Comment: 0 AWG cable for a 4000 W, 12 V inverter is a joke. It will draw 400 Amps. You can't run 400 amps through a 0 AWG cable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the batteries are right next to each other, the wire you use to connect them in parallel will not have a lot of voltage drop in it. So your 3 percent loss does not really come into it. You want to use a wire diameter that can handle the current without getting hot. Each battery will be contributing about 200 Amps to run a 12 V 4000 Watt inverter.

Looking at an [ampacity table](https://www.lapptannehill.com/resources/technical-information/ampacity-chart), that leads us to 3/0 (aka 000) which has a cross-section of about 85 mm2.

For the wire running from the battery to inverter, you will need to use 500 KCMIL wire unless it is a long wire run, in which case you will need even larger wire. If it is not too late, you might consider buying a 24 V inverter and putting the batteries in series so you can use smaller diameter wire.

In my opinion, 4000 Watts is really too large for a 12 V inverter. The whole wiring thing just gets out of hand. I would always go 24 V or 48 V.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cityelectricsupply.com/downloads/Ampacity%20Chart.pdf

Here's a chart to reference amps to wire gauge. The temperature is what the coating can handle, and the acronyms are the type of coating. Make sure you stay in safe levels of what your wire can handle. No need to push the limit and cause potential harm to your system or yourself.

Comment: Does it change anything if the biggest load I plan to use is 2000w? (It’s an induction stove, may briefly surge higher when starting it)